# Knime Data Manipulation

Tags: data-mining, data-cleaning, knime

I have a table with properties as ReadingTime, Frequency and I would like to insert 3 values in between those records where the time difference is greater than 12 hours. I could determine the time difference using the "Time Difference" node available but could not insert rows as per the requirement. Is there any way to attain this in knime ?

Comment: Try writing *code* when asking on a *programming* website.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse what makes a tool's model a programming language? As I see KNIME is a visual programming language for data mining, which is Turing complete (has conditionals, recursion, etc). It is quite hard to describe the workflows on this site without words, as the XML representaion is distributed to multiple files and practically invisible to the users. Do you have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are using [Time Generator](https://www.knime.org/files/node-documentation/org.knime.timeseries.node.generator.DateGeneratorNodeFactory.html) in a chunk loop (with the lagged column and `Use second column` option on the `Time Difference` node), you can generate as many nodes as you want (I assume you already use some switches/if nodes).

Comment: Am I missing something?? I really could not figure out the reason behind my question being down voted .

Comment: @Danny No idea, it was not me who have downvoted your question. I think your problem was valid, you have made the research. The only edgy part might be the " recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" part, but with the node in place it is still not trivial how to combine them together, so I think that does not applies to your question either.
I am glad it helped you solve the problem.